# Append formatted string to already formatted string from UITextView?

Tags: swift, uitextview, swift4

How can a `NSAttributedString` formatted string be appended to an  existing `textView.attributedText` formatted string from UITextView?

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36706394/22470), I can see that a conversion from and to  `NSMutableAttributedString` / `NSAttributedString` can be done with `appendAttributedString()` / `append()` but this **does not work** when I'm pulling and updating a `textView.attributedText` like this:

```
let string2 = NSAttributedString(string: "success", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.green])

let newMutableString = textView.attributedText.copy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
newMutableString.append(string2)

textView.attributedText = newMutableString.copy() as! NSAttributedString
```

Error message:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSConcreteAttributedString' (0x10c7dff30) to 'NSMutableAttributedString' (0x10c7dff80).
```

Comment: Why do you call `.copy()` on your strings?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I tried to mock this other answer ... No real reason. Will try removing it.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth seems that the answer from @ tnguyen is the solution! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to copy it with `mutableCopy` because you want to get a mutable copy from an immutable one:

```
let newMutableString = textView.attributedText.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
```

Comment: Wow that's it! Thanks a lot!